# auto adjust text size to fit a button Android

Tags: java, android, android-button, text-size

Is there a way to auto adjust the text size of a button to be the biggest it can be while stayinh one line, and still fit in the button?

Comment: There's no native support. What you're looking for is here:
[Question asked in another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Comment: whenever I've ported these auto-resize TEXTVIEW examples to extend BUTTON, they don't work ! Would be sweet to see a working Button example with auto-resizable text

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)** (provides support to API level 14).

For example

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Some text"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

The key property here is `app:autoSizeTextType`